# struts2 validator expression

Tags: struts2

Is possible to make this conditional expression validation?:

```
(invitation.id==null and (newText==null or newText.isEmpty()))
```

I've tried several ways, several times, but don't achieve it.
This version is working, but on server-side, and ignore if invitation.id is null or empty... any ideas???:

```
<field name="newText">
   <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
      <param name="expression">!(invitation.id eq null and (newText eq null or newText.empty))</param>
      <message>${getText("validation.required")}</message>
   </field-validator>
</field>
```

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/fieldexpression-validator.html

**what is wrong with the expression??  Thanks!**

Comment: The `required` validator doesn't have `expression` parameter.

Comment: Ok, I fix the question. Is there a way to do this validation, on client-side in standard struts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I used client-side validation width jquery emulating struts2.

I don't like this for compatibility reasons, please if there is a way to do it in a standard way, I'll apreciate any help.

**Removing struts validation:**

```
<!--<field name="newText">
      <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
          <param name="expression">!((invitation.id==null or invitation.id.empty) and (newText==null or newText.empty))</param>
          <message>${getText("validation.required")}</message>
      </field-validator>
    </field>-->
```

**Adding js/jquery code:**

```
function mySubmit() {
    if ((invitationId==null || invitationId<0) && $("#text").val().trim()=='') {
        var trStrutsFieldError='<tr errorfor="text">'+
                                    '<td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><span class="errorMessage">'+strValidationRequired+'</span></td>'+
                                '</tr>';
        $(trStrutsFieldError).insertBefore($("#text").parent().parent());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        $.each($("form").find("span.errorMessage"), function() {  /* <tr errorfor="title"><td colspan="2" align="center"><span classname="errorMessage" class="errorMessage">Campo requerido */
            return false;
        });
        if ($(mySubmit).exists()) {
            if (!mySubmit()) 
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to validate another field (`invitation.id`) into the `newText` Field Validator (i don't think it's possible, but I'm not sure).

However, you could split it into two validators, raising the message corrispondent to the failure case, that is more correct imho;

```xml
<field name="invitation.id">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <message>${getText("validation.invitation.id.required")}</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="newText">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">
           <![CDATA[                 
           newText != null && !newText.trim().empty())
           ]]>
        </param>
        <message>${getText("validation.newText.required")}</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

, if you need to trim it, otherwise it could become simply

```xml
<field name="invitation.id">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <message>${getText("validation.invitation.id.required")}</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="newText">
    <field-validator type="requiredString">
        <message>${getText("validation.newText.required")}</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Note that `required` is for every non-text fields, while `requiredString` is for text fields only.

Expression Validator is very powerful, but it should be used for more complex purposes:

for example, if you want to validate a Date against another one dynamically read (through a Getter) from your Action; lets say you've previously chosen a User, and you need to validate a date from the page against the user Start and End Validity interval; but you want to pass the validation too if the date is not inserted, because it is already handled by the required validator (so you won't raise two messages):

```xml
<field name="inputDate">
    <field-validator type="required">
       <message><![CDATA[ Input Date is mandatory ]]></message>
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression"> 
            <![CDATA[ 
              inputDate==null || 
                (inputDate >= chosenUser.startValidity 
                 && 
                 inputDate <= chosenUser.EndValidity
                ) 
            ]]>            
        </param> 
        <message>
            <![CDATA[Input Date must be included in the User Validity interval 
               (from ${chosenUser.startValidity} to ${chosenUser.endValidity} ) 
            ]]>
        </message>
     </field-validator>
</field>
```

where `chosenUser` is an User object from your Action (`public User getChosenUser()`)
and startValidity and endValidity are properties of the User object (`public Date getEndValidity()`).

And as you can see, the dynamic read can be performed in messages too... this is how powerful expression validator is ;)

Comment: Thanks Andrea, but I don't think it's a solution.  I need exactly to be not valid when: **(invitation.id==null and (newText==null or newText.isEmpty()))**

Comment: then override the validate() method and perform the check server side from your Action, without XML

Comment: I allready do server-side validation, but I want also client-side.  Finally I'm using the jquery answer in this question...

Answer (score 1):

First of all **expression**  is not a valid parameter. If you really want to validate on client side, try to use java-script or jquery for validation. But you have to validate inputs on server - side also because sometimes user could disable the **javascript**  .So in that case you can use struts2 - validation.

for detailed explanation refer http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts2-validation-framework-tutorial-example/

Comment: Witch "expression" are you refering? first or second one?  Anyway I fixed que question and change it for fieldexpression.

Comment: I know i can use javascript and/or jquery, and that I should validate on server-side.  But you are not answering my question.

Comment: well, you can not use customized client-side validation using struts. So you have to wait untill apache launch struts2 validation for client side

Comment: Ok, thanks Arvin, as you can see finally I'm using jquery validation for this case.